What makes the generalized projection different than metric on a Banach space?
I have came across the notion of generalized projection in Banach spaces, introduced by Ya. Alber and has seen many iterative algorithms being solved by using this projection. It helps in finding the common solutions from sets like fixed points, equilibrium problem solution sets, variational analysis etc. Let me introduce it for a smooth Banach space:
Let $X$ be a smooth Banach space, where the duality mapping $J$ is single-valued, and we define $V: X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ by $V(x, y)=\Vert x \Vert^2 - 2 \langle x, Jy \rangle + \Vert y \Vert^2$, for $x, y \in X$. This does not behave like a metric in general Banach spaces. I am not understanding the fact that why it has been employed in Banach spaces, whereas we can always find a metric associated with a Banach space anyway. Can anyone please help me understanding this. Thank you.

Could you make your question a bit more precise, maybe? I have troubles understanding what you aim at. (Could be me, of course.)

Sure. I have difficulty in understanding why the generalized projection operator has been employed even though we always find a metric for every Banach space. Also, in one paper, the concept of best proximinality has been introduced by using the generalized projection (see Guan, Wei-Bo, and Wen Song. "W-approximative compactness and continuity of the generalized projection operator in Banach spaces." Journal of approximation theory). So far, I have understood that the concept is restrictive. So, what is the motivation behind using this operator anyway? I hope my question is clear.
